# How to show error message in JSP using json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlet-3.0

I am doing an application only using JSP,Servlet,Mysql and Jquery. I want to show an error message from Jquery which set to json object (in servlet).
Here I have attached my code

- JSP/Jquery

  ```
  $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
          $.ajax({
              type : 'GET',
              url : 'createaction',
              data : {
                  code : document.getElementById("code").value,
                  descr : document.getElementById("descr").value,
                  checkboxVal : "create" 
              },
              success : function(responseText) {
                  alert(responseText);
              }
          });
  ```
- Servlet

  ```
  JSONObject json      = new JSONObject();
  String chkVal = request.getParameter("checkboxVal");


      if (chkVal.equals("create")){
          try {
              create(request, response);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              try {
                  json.put("error", e);
              } catch (JSONException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              }
              response.setContentType("application/json");
              response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
              System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaa");
          }
      }
  ```

Here I tried to show sqlexception to the front end (as a test)..Please assist me..

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't post your entire. Anyway if you want to show error in a popup.

**ErrorController.java**

```
public class ErrorController extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    final String chkVal = request.getParameter("checkboxVal");

    if (chkVal.equals("create")) {
      try {
        throw new SQLException();
      } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
          json.put("error", e);
        } catch (final JSONException e1) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**errorJsp.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'GET',
                        url : '/message/createaction',
                        data : {
                            code : document.getElementById("code").value,
                            descr : document.getElementById("descr").value,
                            checkboxVal : "create" 
                        },
                        success : function(responseText) {
                            alert(responseText.error);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="code" type="hidden" value="123456">
            <input id="descr" type="hidden" value="Description...">
            <input id="submitbtn" type="button" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC 
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ErrorController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.application.ErrorController</servlet-class>

        <description>Ma première servlet de test.</description>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ErrorController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/createaction</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: responsetext.error is giving me the error in alert.. Thank you very much.. I am using servlet 3.0.. So I did not use web.xml